# Rails/Ruby: Performing calculate on ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation (including custom foreign_key)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, rails-activerecord

I hope I am asking the proper question in the title, as my issue feels like it should be quite trivial yet I'm having terrible luck figuring it out.

I have two basic `models` with a standard `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship:

```rb
class StandingEvent < Event
  belongs_to :standing, foreign_key: 'actor_id'
end

class Standing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :standing_events
end
```

My goal is simple: **To calculate the SUM of a field in a collection of `StandingEvents` records acquired *through* a `Standing` association.**  As expected, this collection is of `type` `StandingEvent::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`.

Ignoring everything else and cutting it down to the barest of bones, I get an error when running the following:

```rb
@standing = Standing.find(4)
@standing.standing_events.sum(:change)
```

The error produced is found below:

`` Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.standing_id' in 'where clause':
SELECT SUM(`events`.`change`) AS sum_id FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`actor_type` IN ('StandingEvent') AND `events`.`standing_id` = 4 ``

So, as seen from the above error, the *exact* problem is that the generated SQL query is trying to use `standing_id` as the column name (presumably because of the associated record) instead of the **actual** column name specified in the model itself (`actor_id`).

This issue only comes up when using a `calculate` method (such as `sum`), since I'm using both these models and their association very heavily throughout the application without any issue.

The only way "around" this issue that I've found so far seems very poor (and strikes me as unnecessary), which is essentially to chain my `where` clauses and `sum` through the base class, rather then using a previously gathered set of associated records:

```rb
@standing = Standing.find(4)
StandingEvent.where(standing: @standing).sum(:change)
```

The above code performs the calculation without issue, but since I'd like to perform multiple calculations upon the same collection within a single request, it seems like a very poor solution to re-query the entire set every time as above (though perhaps I don't understand Rails enough, to be fair).

As mentioned in my question title, I can't help but wonder if this is a bug (for lack of a better term) of some sort related to the use of the `foreign_key` field I specified for the `child` association (in this case, the `foreign_key` for `StandingEvent`'s `Standing` association is renamed to `actor_id`).

Any and all insight would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to specify the `foreign_key` on both sides of the association

`has_many :standing_events, foreign_key: :actor_id`

Comment: My goodness, that was painfully simple to fix.  Ugh, don't I feel silly!  Thanks so much for the quick response and easy solution Ben!